# Conditional Include in Jade + Express

Tags: node.js, express, pug

How can one use if -else statement on "include" in jade??

For example, if I have two separate navigation bar templates navbar.jade and navbar_notloggedin.jade

I would like to do:

```
input(type='hidden', value= user.user)#username

- if(user.user!="")
  include navbar
- else if(user.user=="")
  include navbar_notloggedin
```

Comment: And what happens if you execute that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use,

```
-if (user.user)
 include navbar
-else
 include navbar_notloggedin
```

The if statement will check whether the variable is defined or not, not whether it is an empty string or not. However, I assume you are not storing empty string values for user.

Comment: You can even omit the leading dashes.

Comment: how to use include in jade template?

Comment: got the example https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/examples/jade/views/layout.jade