# Render a partial view in another partial view in node js with express framework and jade template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, node.js, express, pug

To render a partial view in ASP.net MVC, we have a **RenderPartial** method in Html helper class.
example:-

**index.cshtml**

```
<div>
  @Html.RenderPartial("test.cshtml")
</div>
```

**test.cshtml**

```
<div>hello</div>
```

Do we have any equivalent method in node js also?

I am using Express framework with jade template. I searched a lot but did not find any relevant information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859942/conditional-include-in-jade-express Is this what you are looking for

Comment: thanks, this is exactly i was looking for. pls post this in answer, I will mark it

Answer (score 0):

```
res.partial('comment', { collection: comments });
```

Comment: I want to use in a view, not in any action.

Comment: would be nice if you explained what this actually is.. all i see is one line that might not make sense to some people